# Where to manage users right for mysite?

Tags: permissions, my-site

A user needs additional permissions for his/her mysite.

A user came by and wanted to add webpart to his mysite. However, that option is grayed out. How do I grant additional permission to that user (for his mysite) so that he/she can add webpart to his/her mysite?

Answer (score 2):

Have the user check what features are enabled. Most web parts are enabled or disabled by the features activated on the site or site collection. The user is his own Site Collection Owner, so should be able to enable or disable features on his site.

Comment: cool. let me try that.

Comment: I went to the user and he doesn't even have Site Settings. so manually typed _layouts/settings.aspx and got correlation error stuff.